# Disable commands for users

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, users

I have users that login automatically via ssh to a script I defined instead of a shell. The script basically launches a program which has a shell-escape in it which would allow the user to execute commands outside of the program. If I can disable all commands of a user, then that shell-escape function won't matter. How can I disable all commands to be executed from any given user? For clarity, in /etc/passwd, the shell is set to /usr/user.sh and in user.sh, a program is launched.